# An alternative to TempData[ ] in API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to move information like objects or anything else between actions or controllers.
But in my `API` project, when I type `TempData[ ]` inside the body of the method, the IDE does not recognize it.
I used to use `TempData[ ]` in RazorPage, but now it does not work on my API without View.

Can `TempData [ ]` be used in `API`? In what form?

If not, what is the alternative?

Thanks to those who help me!

Comment: What do you want to do with `TempData` in the first place? TempData is used to transfer data from the controller to the view. There's no view in an API.

Comment: As I wrote in the description above, I want to move data between actions or controllers without having to send and receive it as an argument. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Does your class inherit *(directly or indirectly)* from [the `Controller` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-6.0)? If not, it won't have a `TempData` property.

Comment: Yes, it inherits from the `ControllerBase`. But it still does not know `TempData`. Should I make arrangements for `TempData`? @Richard Deeming

Comment: `move data between actions or controllers` is unclear.  Data isn't passed between controllers or actions. In MVC TempData is used to store data *in session storage* and make it available to the next request in the same session. After that, the data is deleted. This is useful in web apps where the next action taken by a user may need data from the previous one. HTTP APIs are stateless though and won't even have a session unless configured for this. There are no cookies and no session cookies in an HTTP API, nor is there any expectation that calls will come in sequence

Comment: Which request is the "next" if a single client makes 10 concurrent requests?

Comment: As I said, `TempData` is defined on `Controller`, not `ControllerBase`.

Comment: Thanks for the your response! It worked for me. But I thought there wasn't a big difference between a `Controller` and  `Controller Base`! Which is better to inherit? @Richard Deeming

Comment: It's not enough to inherit from Controller. `TempData` is an interface over session storage. While web apps have user sessions, HTTP APIs do not. Statelessness is a key concept of HTTP APIs. That's why TempData is available in MVC through Controller, but not Web APIs and ControllerBase. To use session storage you'd have to add it in `Startup.cs`.  Unless you enable sessions, your `TempData` will be empty in the "next" request